# How to sense current with OPAMP?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, adc, current-measurement

I want to sense the current that battery supplies to the low current (few mA) circuit. As everyone said before, forcing discrete design does not make sense, so I decided to apply simple OPAMP & bjt based design. 
I've tried the design for very different resistance values and it worked well as long as Rload<= 37Ohms.

In real case, on the other hand, Vsense was always less than 2-3 mV whatever the load resistance was, and the output of the OPAMP was quite different than the simulation. It is genereally impossible to get the same results with simulation in the real case; but, I could not find the problem with the design?

What could be the problem?

Here is the datasheet of LM358: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f05nY5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

edit2:

Comment: 1. Why are you building a differential amplifier instead of buying an IC one? 2. Can you give a schematic of what you're doing? It's not clear to me what you mean by "single ended CM amplifier".

Comment: @ThePhoton I added a schematic as you requested. IC is very simple solution ; but, the project is very cost sensitive, which is why I avoid ICs.

Comment: If you use discrete transistors you will have substantial offset and error due to mismatch.  You're way better off with a cheap op-amp.  If you must use discretes, some emitter degeneration resistors will help. You're not really planning on 1A of tail current are you?

Comment: of course not, just forgot to change :) thank you @JohnD

Comment: When you say "minimum cost" can I assume you already have the transistors on hand, but not an opamp? While opamps can be *very* cheap, you can't beat zero for cost. If this is the case, which BJT / FET do you have on hand?

Comment: Don't you need matched transistors for this?  Your BC847's cost ~$0.06 (on digikey) you can get an opamp for ~$0.10.  (Not much savings,  and where is your 2mA current source... another transistor?)

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you show will work, however there are limitations.

First, the output voltage cannot exceed the load voltage, in fact it can't quite get there because of Vce(sat).

Secondly, the op-amp cannot swing very close to the supply voltage, so the output voltage cannot exceed about 2.5V with a 5.2V supply, 2 Volts would be safer.

Thirdly, the input common-mode range of the op-amp is Vcc - 2V over range, so V2 must be no more than 5.2 - 2V = 3.2V. You need a higher voltage than Vbat to supply the op-amp. This is one reason why people are suggesting you buy the boutique parts- they are designed to have a common-mode range that includes the positive supply rail. T**his is probably your biggest hurdle**- even if you're happy with 0-1V or 0-2V out, you need a higher supply voltage if your V2 is actually the same as the 5.2V, maybe 7.5V.

Fourth, the offset voltage of that particular 2-cent op-amp can be as much as 9mV, which would represent an error of +/-9mA in the measured current. That can be zero'd out but it will typically drift +/-7uA/°C so for a 50°C change you could see 0.35mA change in the measurement. You can cancel out the error due to input bias current by adding 1K in series with the inverting input, but it's likely not worth it. Note that if the offset voltage of the particular op-amp you're using happens to be the wrong polarity you'll get no reading at all until the current exceeds the offset voltage divided by the value of the sense resistor since this circuit can only output positive voltage. So if your current to be measured is less than 9mA you may never see a signal (usually the offset voltage is better than that, but you can't count on it).

And finally, there will be a small error due the finite gain of the transistor, likely less than the tolerance of the 1 ohm resistor, but probably more temperature sensitive.

Comment: Maximum output voltage about 3V-3.3V will be sufficient for me; since, the uP is supplied with 3.3V Vcc. Vbat is 3.7V, so, the problem is most likely to be the common mode range of OPAMP, as you said. An OPAMP with higher input common-mode range or higher supply voltage will solve the problem, I think. Or do I have to buy special current monitor ICs? What do you think? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: @vilacikovski A rail-to-rail input/output op-amp will solve most of these problems, but Vos must be low to be useful as my comments about accuracy indicate, and the RRIO input op amp with zero drift will be much more expensive than a 358. Suggest you price it both ways.

Comment: In addition, input common mode range of LM358 is specified as Vcc-1.5V in the datasheet. Since Vbat=3.7V, the input common mode voltage in my design never exceeds 3.7V. Does it still cause problem? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: @vilacikovski it's 2V over the temperature range. Using 25C and 'typical' figures can get you into a world of hurt- a field failure is enormously expensive in direct cost and reputation.

Comment: I think the solution will be to increase cost by using RRIO OPAMP or current monitor IC. Thanks for advices. @SpehroPefhany

Comment: I've conducted some experiments by taking your suggestions into account such as providing 12V Vcc. Moreover, output voltage of OPAMP exceeds 2.5V, it's about 3.6V under 12V Vcc supply. As a result, I measure 1.22mA current as 2.8-2.9mA. With higher currents, 9mA for example, the error is negligible, on the other hand. What do you suggest?

Comment: Offset voltage is too high- better op amp

Answer (score 0):

For anything less than ~20mA why not just use a TIA opamp to ground?
If the load can't float, then can you float the power supply?

Comment: well, it's been a long time after this question and I've completed the design. Even so, thanks for your interest after 1 months:)